# Nested index in Lua: a['0'].b['0']?

Tags: lua

I'd like to implement some Lua data structure to achieve the following syntax:

1. `units` -> returns a table of units.
2. `units[0]` -> returns a number.
3. `units[0].properties` -> returns a table of properties.
4. `units[0].properties[0]` -> return the property of units[0], which is also a number.

The first 2 steps are trivial given a number indexed table.
But can I achieve all 4 requirements at the same time?

I was thinking about creating `units` with customized `__index` metamethod. Is it the right direction?

Comment: What is a "primitive type" such that `primitive_type.properties` would result in a table?

Comment: All `units[k]` should have `__index` metamethod.

Comment: @NicolBolas I mean boolean, number, string :) Most likely just a number.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I just updated my description. I'd like to have `units[0]` to returns a number and I think a number cannot have the `__index` metamethod?

Comment: @TangKe - Yes, you have to make your "primitive types" a tables.  For example, `setmetatable({value = 42}, {__index = ...})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could set the metatable for all numbers (via `debug.setmetatable`) and use a `__index` metamethod to resolve the properties:

```
local properties_by_nums = {
  {42},
  {23},
}

local num_mt = {
  __index = function(n, i)
    if i == 'properties' then
      return properties_by_nums[n]
    end
    return nil
  end
}

debug.setmetatable(0, num_mt)

units = {1, 5}

print(type(units))                                          -- table
print(units[1], type(units[1]))                             -- 1, number
print(type(units[1].properties))                            -- table
print(units[1].properties[1], type(units[1].properties[1])) -- 42, table
```

The (probably cleaner) alternative would be to define your unit values as tables which *behave* like numbers.  This can be achieved by implement the metamethods `__add`, `__mul`, etc.

Comment: It works! One thing I don't understand is why is units[1].properties a table? How does the __index metamethod work in this scenario?

Comment: I left `units[1].properties` as a normal table (the `{42}` in `properties_by_nums`), as I saw no need to use a metatable. The `__index` metamethod on numbers takes two arguments, the given number and the index that is to be looked up.  The only field is `properties`. The actual properties are then look up in `properties_by_nums` via index on the number whose properties we are looking for. Does that make sense?